# How to change schedule_interval of an already deployed DAG?

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that has been deployed to Airflow. I see it in the Airflow UI. In order for me to change schedule_interval of my DAG, I need to redeploy the python script.

Is it possible to do with without deploying the script? Maybe there's an Airflow CLI command?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Variables to handle it in case you want to change the shedule without deploy new python script.
In your Dag code use:

```
SCHEDULE_INTERVAL = Variable.get('schedule', default_var='@hourly')
```

And use this param to in your Dag args:

```
default_args = {
'schedule_interval': SCHEDULE_INTERVAL
}
```

So whenever you need to change the schedule you just go to Admin UI > Admin > Variables > set new value and refresh the Dag.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

DAGs in Airflow are defined in code, the only option to change your DAG's schedule_interval is to change and redeploy the code.

Comment: it seems that if you have a database where you store parameters, you can update them in the database and have your dag read them from there, even if those are design time parameters.